# convert from uri to Location object

Tags: java, android

I made a QR code scanner that gets the URL to google map location, look like this

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=43.068888,68.466797

how do I convert from string / uri to longitude and latitude?

Comment: Have you tried to extract out the `q=43.068888,68.466797` yet?

Comment: Sounds like a basic parsing problem, i doubt there is a official function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=43.068888,68.466797";
String[] geoCoordinates = Uri.parse(url).getQueryParameter("q").split(",");
double latitude = Double.valueOf(geoCoordinates[0]);
double longitude = Double.valueOf(geoCoordinates[1]);
```

Comment: Updated example to double.